# I am getting a error while using the yq -Y command

Tags: yaml, yq

I am looking to add an environment variable to a yaml file from the command line. I used yq. This is the command:

```
cat mytemplate.yml | yq -Y '.services.samson.environment += {"newKey":"newVal"}'
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'Y' in -Y
Usage:
  yq [flags]
  yq [command]
```

Any work-arounds for this

Answer (score 4):

You are probably confusing [yq, the jq wrapper for YAML](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/) with [yq, the jq reimplementation for YAML](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) which are two different projects.

You have the second one installed but your usage of `-Y` indicates you need the first one, since only that one has such an option. So you need to uninstall the currently installed `yq` and then install the other one.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for clarifying the difference!

Comment: To whom have the same issue: `brew uninstall yq && brew install python-yq`